# what happens when user abruptly shuts app in android?

Tags: android, linux, operating-system, system, cpu-architecture

Suppose a user is running an app and then suddenly he closes the app.
Now, will the process in which the app was currently running be immediately killed?
If the answer to the above question is yes then it will mean at the end of some calculation that was being done in my app regarding which I had to save something to the database which could not be done because the process was killed. is it so?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "closing". If the user just closes the activities with the back button, the application process can still exist in background for some time, but it has least possible priority by the system, so system will most likely kill it very soon. If the user just hides the app with the home button, the process will stay in memory until the system needs extra resources to support any foreground processes the user is currently interacting with. If the user opens 'recent apps' and swipes out your application he essentially asks the system to kill the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android guarantees to keep your process while the app has either an active `Activity` or a **foreground** `Service`. Right after your `Activity` has received `onPause()` event and there are no foreground `Service`s running, the process hosting your app may be killed at any time, which means that even the `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be invoked in some cases. Thus, you should save the important data right in the `onPause()` lifecycle callback or use foreground `Service`s.

Look here for details: [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), [App's process lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)